# Propagating Baggages with Opentelemetry.Baggage API in .NET

Tags: asp.net, event-propagation, distributed-tracing, open-telemetry

Say I have 3 microservices, and I want to trace requests using OpenTelemetry/Jaeger UI. How do I add baggages that propagate through the spans? Say I have one API called WeatherForecast which performs a get request to another service called Matrix, and I create a baggage like this:

```
    var res = HttpClient.GetStringAsync("http://localhost:5002/Matrix").Result;
    Baggage.Current.SetBaggage("weatherforecastid", "abced123");`
```

How do I get the current baggage to propagate through the Matrix Service (which calls another service)? I tried using Baggage.Current.SetBaggage thinking it would be referencing the baggage from the WeatherForecast, however it appears it only created a new baggage and did not propagate the previous.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/blob/main/src/OpenTelemetry.Api/README.md), this is enabled by default:

> Baggage API allows users to add context to metric, traces, and logs. Baggage can be propagated out of proc using Propagators. OpenTelemetry SDK ships a BaggagePropagator and enables it by default.

So if all your services have OpenTelemetry properly configured, the Baggage should be preserved between services through HTTP calls.